# VS debugger stops without exception when a thread uses a COM class

Tags: vb.net, com

I have a VB.NET application which starts a thread and the thread instantiate a COM class, from a C++ COM in-proc module, using a PIA, and uses its methods. Been working for years.

Just converted the COM server to VB.NET an ran into the following problem with the VS debugger: stepping in the code of the thread, the line of code which refers to the VB.NET COM server, trying to step over, execution would stop, no exception, debugger would end, thread ends.

I just found that the problem was caused by the fact that I did not specify an apartment model for the thread. Specifiying STAThread would fix it.

Is there a way to configure VS debugger to get more than an abort during this kind of bug? In Debugger/Exception, turning on all "stop if exception is raised" did not do the job.

Comment: There *may* be a Managed Debugging Assistant (MDA) that can be turned on to do this.  Read through the docs and see if there is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think I was hit by a corruption or bug in the COM layer, creating instabilities. I am pretty sure I know why now, so I have a solution. Will used MDA next time this happens. Thanks for the tip !